# Running R script using VBA

Tags: r, excel, vba

I'm trying to create a button on Excel that runs an R script I created. This is the VBA code I tried:

```
Sub RunRscript()

Dim shell As Object
Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
Dim style As Integer: style = 1
Dim errorCode As Integer
Dim path As String
path = "RScript C:\R_code\Forecast.R"
errorCode = shell.Run(path, style, waitTillComplete)
End Sub
```

But that also returns an error -> Run-time error '-2147024894 (80070002) Automation Error.

I much appreciate any help!

Comment: Seems like if your R code has a problem then maybe address that first?

Comment: Well, I can run the Rcode on Rstudio error fee.

Comment: Use a fully qualified path to the executable you want to run. Your current code depends upon the PATH variable and lookup.

Comment: Where does your R script read its inputs from?

Comment: @HackSlash Can you elaborate on what a fully qualified path is? Or maybe tell me where to find more info about it? Thanks!

Comment: The location of `RScript.exe` - not just `RScript`

Comment: Thank you! I made it run from VBA changing the path as suggested.
`path = """C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.1\bin\Rscript.exe"" C:\R_code\Forecast.R""`

Comment: Just be aware that this will break when you update R to a new version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was to use a fully qualified path to the executable you want to run in the shell. You can't rely on PATH variable lookups. It's much safer this way.

```vb
Sub RunRscript()

    Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
    Dim style As Integer: style = 1
    Dim errorCode As Integer
    Dim path As String
    path = """C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.1\bin\Rscript.exe"" C:\R_code\Forecast.R""

    With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        errorCode = .Run(path, style, waitTillComplete)
    End With
End Sub
```

NOTE: If you need to quickly find the location of an executable in your PATH variable you can run `where RScript` from `cmd.exe` and it will tell you the fully qualified path.